# selecting all class within this in query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

well right now I am doing something like this to find all textbox values which has the same class name.

```
    function generalBottom(anchor) {
     var sends = $('input[data-name^="noValues"]').map(function(){
      $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
       return $(this).val();
     }).get();
    }
```

and i call this function on a onclick of submit button like `generalBottom(this)`
and I have something like as per my requirement
  [image]
When I click submit button of `User` I call a general function passing `this` as a parameter, but the above code gives me the text values of `client` as well 
`["perfect", "hyperjack", "julie", "annoying", "junction", "convulated"]`,   which is undesired, I want only `["annoying", "junction", "convulated"]` using my anchor params.
How to do this via my `this` parameter, I thought to traverse through my tags using children(), parent() but I won't be knowing how many fields user have added as its all dynamic, user can add as many values(text boxes).

I tried this

1) `$(anchor).find('.rightAbsNo')`

2) `$(anchor).find('input[data-name^="noValues"]')`

3)  `$(anchor).find('.rightAbsNo').map(function () {
            console.log($(this).find('. showNoButton')); })`

None of this worked for me.

My html is somewhat like this, code

```
  <div id="attach0" class="leftbottomno">
  <div style="overflow: hidden" class="leftbottomAbsolute" id="">   
  <form> 
  <span class="absno"><input type="text" required="" 
  id="absdelete" data-inputclass="leftbottomAbsoluteNo_class"     
  value="" class="leftbottomabsolutenotest keys" data-value="" 
  style="margin-bottom:4px; color: #1c1c1c;"> </span>  
  <a onclick="addAbsoluteValues(this);" style="margin-left: 50px"> 
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle color-blue-grey-lighter"></i> </a>  
  </form> 

  <a onclick="deleteAbsoluteEmpty(this);> </a><br> 

  <div class="rightAbsNo" id="yesValueattach"> 
  <div class="rightAbsNoValue"> 
  <input type="text" id="nonattach" placeholder="values" 
  data-name="noValues" data-inputclass="absYes_class"  value="annoying"   
  class="showNoButton showActivity value" data-value=""> 
  <button type="button" onclick="generalBottom(this);">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button> 
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightAbsNo" id="yesValueattach"> 
  <div class="rightAbsNoValue" id=""> <input type="text" 
  data-name="noValues" data-inputclass="absYes_class" subattribute="" 
  value="" class="showNoButton showActivity value" data-value=""> 
  <button type="button" onclick="generalBottom(this);">

  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button> 
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightAbsNo" id="yesValueattach"> 
  <div class="rightAbsNoValue" id=""> 
  <input type="text" data-name="noValues" 
  data-inputclass="absYes_class" placeholder="values" subattribute="" 
  value="junction" class="showNoButton showActivity value" 
  data-value="" > 
  <button type="button" style="display: none;"    
  onclick="generalBottom(this);">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </button> 
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: what is `anchor`?

Comment: Just a parameter name .... Actual argument is this and formal argument I named it as anchor

Comment: It may not be a parent of `.rightAbsNo` elements.

Comment: You can see in html screenshot, rightAbsNo is grand parent of my submit button

Comment: From what I understand, you have a single form and several submit buttons, and just want to submit the input value when you click the button near it right?

Comment: Yes and all have same class

Comment: can you check what `anchor` is with `console.log`? It may be returning the whole form object.

Comment: anchor gives me `<button type="submit" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit stylebutton" onclick="generalBottom(this);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>`
so i was thinking to traverse to those input fields , so i was using find and selecting all class but it didnt work

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you think it's right. We are expecting this from you. Don't just ask and go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define a container to the groups with something like :

```
<div class="container">input groups</div>
<div class="container">input groups</div>
```

and change `<button type='submit'>` to `<button type='button'>` to prevent submitting the form.

Then change your function to this:

```
function generalBottom(anchor) {
    var all_inputs = $(anchor).parent(".container").find("input");
    var input = $(anchor).siblings('input').first();
    all_inputs.each(function(){
        $(this).val(input.val());
    });
}
```

Comment: thats work perfect for current submit button and for that text box value, i want all text box values above of that which comes under same parent, can that anchor tag traverse across  its siblings parents , when i click submit button of `convulated` i should get ["annoying", "junction", "convulated"]

Comment: Yes, you should wrap your groups with containers. That's what I'm telling you.

Comment: dont you think they are already in groups in <div class="rightAbsNo">, structure is like this , `<div class="rightAbsNo"><div class="rightAbsNoValue" ><input box><button> </div></div>`

Comment: Nope, they are wrapping one input and one button. What I say is they need another wrapper which contains "annoying, junction, convulated" inputs and buttons' containers (which you refer as "rightAbsNo") only.

Comment: If you've pasted a code instead of a picture, I would demonstrate you. Code images are waste of our time.

Comment: I have updated the html code, can u look at it, i think for me the container class is `leftbottomAbsolute `

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfLb5ynr/5/)

first `$(anchor).siblings(input)` find inputs

then go through each element from first step and return their value

```
    function generalBottom(anchor) {
        var input = 'input[data-name^="noValues"]'
        var values = $.map($(anchor).siblings(input), (elemnt, index)=>{
            return elemnt.value
        })
        $('#shows').val(values.join())
    }

    $('button').on('click',function(){
        generalBottom(this)
    })
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, i had to select the grandparent of anchor in my case.